# Loading a resource file from a JAR, outside classpath, in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources, classpath, classloader

Assume an application developed in `IntelliJ`, to be packaged in a single JAR and use "resource" files that

- Can be located in any package (not only in a `resources` folder)
- May have non-standard file extensions (may even be Java files)
- Are not present in all classpaths (e.g., to avoid circular dependencies)

If a class (say, `MyClass`) in a package (say, `com.example.pack`) is given a path to such a "resource" that resides outside its classpath and attempts to access it via

```
 MyClass.class.getClassloader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
```

the `InputStream` object returned in `IntelliJ` unit tests is (expectedly) `null` due to the classpath. However, when the code is executed it works, since everything is in the same JAR.

For example, bundling all the packages of the application in the same JAR (say, `MyApplication.jar`) and running something like

```
java -cp MyApplication.jar com.example.pack.MyClass
```

from the command line, does produce a non-`null` `InputStream`.

Is there any way to configure `IntelliJ` to somehow "know" that all packages belong to the same `JAR` and thus treat them accordingly, so that the above call to `getResourceAsStream()` works?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to configure that is to add the module containing the resource files as a dependency to the module containing the tests. Then IntelliJ IDEA will include that module into the runtime classpath of the tests, and the `getResourceAsStream()` call will work.

Comment: This does not cover modules that already depend on other modules, leading to circular dependencies. Otherwise, the answer is correct. Thanks and +1.

Comment: The IntelliJ project structure does support circular dependencies, so this is not an issue by itself.